# Create a board with reference images on a specific subject

Tags: windows, linux, open-source, images

I often assemble a small set of images as references for an element of art or game development. I then have to flip through the files or open them in multiple windows.

Is there any software that behaves like a piece of poster board on which you can pin a set of images? It would be helpful to have separate boards for each element and flip between those instead. Or, another type of software that reasonably fills the same role.

Open-source is preferable.

Comment: Does it need to work offline? If not, maybe it would be easier/faster to use Pinterest, as it enables you to do all the things you want (although, granted, Pinterest is not open source)?